# Повторение частицы при однородных членах

Tags: частица

Есть предложение:

Потому что ключевыми условиями успеха инновационного ли развития, импортозамещения, импортоопережения, экспортной ориентации являются доступ к капиталу, новейшим технологиям и внешним рынкам, рост объема госзаказа и рост цены в развиваемом сегменте, чтобы была возможность компенсировать затраты и инвестировать в развитие.

Надо ли здесь везде повторять частицу? И тогда предложение будет иметь такой вид:

Потому что ключевыми условиями успеха инновационного ли развития, импортозамещения ли, импортоопережения ли, экспортной ли ориентации являются доступ к капиталу, новейшим технологиям и внешним рынкам, рост объема госзаказа и рост цены в развиваемом сегменте, чтобы была возможность компенсировать затраты и инвестировать в развитие.

Answer (score 1):

А вы используйте союз ***ли...или*** и просто ***или***: *...инновационного ли развития или импортозамещения,  импортоопережения или экспортной ориентации являются доступ к капиталу...*

Comment: Екатерина, а вам не кажется,  что само предложение составлено некорректно? Союз "чтобы" должен указывать на цель. Но в первой части нет цели.

Comment: Отвечала на вопрос о повторяющемся союзе. Вы правы, есть над чем поработать. Например, не рекомендуется начинать предложение с "потому что".

Comment: Но иногда это логически следует из контекста...

Comment: Аленка, что следует?

Comment: То, что это предложение начинается с "потому что".

Answer (score 0):

В качестве варианта:

Потому что ключевыми условиями успеха инновационного **ли** развития **или** импортозамещения, импортоопережения и экспортной ориентации **является** доступ к капиталу, новейшим технологиям и внешним рынкам, рост объема госзаказа и рост цены в развиваемом сегменте, чтобы была возможность компенсировать затраты и инвестировать в развитие.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ключевыми условиями успеха инновационного ли развития, импортозамещения ли, импортоопережения ли, экспортной ли ориентации являются доступ к капиталу...
Частица ЛИ придаёт  предложению разговорный, просторечный оттенок. Можно попробовать её заменить повторяющимся союзом И.  Потому что ключевыми условиями успеха И инновационного развития, И импортозамещения, И импортоопережения, И экспортной ориентации являются доступ к капиталу... Сохранится стиль.